# How to use babel-plugin-module-resolver to set an alias for the root path and disable other root imports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-plugin

I would like to do imports like this `import Foo from '~/components/Foo'`

https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver

If I set my `.babelrc` to:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": "./",
      "alias": {
        "~/": "./"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

I have also tried (and lots of other combinations):

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ".",
      "alias": {
        "~": "."
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Then I can use it in scripts like so:

```js
import Foo from 'components/Foo'
```

1. It doesn't work if I do `import Foo from '~/components/Foo'` (I would expect it to)
2. I want to **force** users to have to prepend the `~/` so there aren't multiple usage patterns.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./",]
      "alias": {
        "~/": "./"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

try it

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer